# Add class to child that fits url

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, location

I've made a one page layout website, where the menu doesn't show the active/current link, when users come from Google or bookmarked it.

I've made a script that works fine, but as you see.... it look horribly. How can I do this smart??

```
//Set .active to current page link
    if (location.href.indexOf("#2") != -1) {
        $("#menu li:nth-child(1) a ").addClass("active");
    }
    if (location.href.indexOf("#3") != -1) {
        $("#menu li:nth-child(2) a ").addClass("active");
    }
    if (location.href.indexOf("#4") != -1) {
        $("#menu li:nth-child(3) a ").addClass("active");
    }
    if (location.href.indexOf("#5") != -1) {
        $("#menu li:nth-child(4) a ").addClass("active");
    }
    if (location.href.indexOf("#6") != -1) {
        $("#menu li:nth-child(5) a ").addClass("active");
    }
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
$("#menu li:nth-child(" + ( location.hash.slice(1) - 1 ) + ") a ").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Why not? Seems to work fine for me. The slice just trims off the "#" -- it doesn't limit the length of the number.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I look at slice and thinks about charAt :-D

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I knew it would be simple. Thank you alot... :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var m = location.href.match(/#(\d+)/);
if (m) {
  var index = parseInt(m[1]) - 1;
  if (index >= 1)
    $("#menu li:nth-child("+index+") a ").addClass("active");
}
```